# What are numbers of the colorbar in a 2d histogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, colorbar

I have plot a [2D histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRo2a.png) with the following python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
x,y,z,a = np.loadtxt('bca_16_t1.txt', unpack=True, delimiter=',')
plt.hist2d(a, z,bins=(200, 200), cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.ylim([2.0, 4.6])
plt.xlim([700, 1300])
ax = plt.axes()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(50))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.2))
plt.grid()
plt.colorbar(fraction=0.15, shrink=1.0, aspect=20)
plt.show()
```

I have the following questions about it:

1. How do i remove the white space at the left most end of the plot?
2. What is the unit of the numbers against the colour bar and what do those numbers mean?

Any help regarding this will be much appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: You are plotting a histogram. The histogram values tell you how often some input data lies in the respective bin.  In this case some 26 events happened within 1180 and 1181 "corrected intensity" and between 3.655 and 3.658 "hardness" (numbers are just guesses looking coarsely at the picture).

Comment: Maybe spend some time browsing [The Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html). I highly recommend working through [The Tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html)  - it will help you understand where to look for the customizations you want to accomplish (now and in the future).

Comment: Regarding the first question, you do set the limits yourself. If you remove the lines that do that it should automatically fit to your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

1. How do i remove the white space at the left most end of the plot?

   A. The white space is due to improper X-axis scale. Remove the lower limit of the X-axis scale to get rid of white space. To set only upper limit of the X-axis scale, add the following line:

   plt.xlim(xmax=1300)
2. What is the unit of the numbers against the colour bar and what do those numbers mean?

   A. The unit of the colour bar is binned 'Events' or 'Data points'. You can change the scale by changing the 'bins' parameter in plt.hist2d.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set `xlim` to be the minimum of your data in x axis. You set 700 but seems like you can do slightly higher than that.
2. the numbers should be your `z` values.

Comment: How can i set the plt.xlim to take the minimum value from my data automatically? The unit if the colour bar doesn't look like it is related to my data at all. The unit of my X-axis is counts/second. The Y-axis does not have any unit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my answers are only guesses. I have no experience with that package.

1. To remove the white space at the left most of the plot set the `plt.xlim` to something bigger than 700. Try with your lowest value in that axis.
2. I bet that the unit in the color bar is related to your data. Which is the unit of your data? And what your data mean?

Comment: How can i set the plt.xlim to take the minimum value from my data automatically? The unit if the colour bar doesn't look like it is related to my data at all. The unit of my X-axis is counts/second. The Y-axis does not have any unit.

Comment: Apply the miminum function to your X data set and put the result as the parameter for xlim.

Regarding your units... well, it looks like you are reading a file with 4 columns, x, y, z, and a. Check the units of column z. You are the owner of the data, you should know what are you working on!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can limit the left using `plt.xlim(xmin=x.min())`.
2. The values on the `z` axis are the frequency of your data in the corresponding bin, for example if you have 5 elements in the range `700<x<703 and 2<y<2.013` the colorbar would show 5. If you want them to be normalized (in the range zero to one), then you should use `hist2d(...,normed=True)`